# Java, if statements inside actionPerformed() not executed

Tags: java, user-interface

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class MyGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    JButton btnA;
    public MyGUI()
    {
        setTitle("Test GUI");
        setSize(500, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setLayout(null);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JButton btnA=new JButton("A");
        btnA.setSize(100, 20);
        btnA.setLocation(0, 0);
        btnA.addActionListener(this);

        add(btnA);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        System.out.println("Action detected");
        if(e.getSource().equals(btnA))
            System.out.println("A was pressed");
    }
}
```

I'm starting out on Java GUIs. I have a button. However, when I click the button, the third print statement isn't executed, even though it's supposed to, judging from the event's toString() info. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are declaring a local variable when you execute this line:

```
JButton btnA=new JButton("A");
```

The member field `btnA` remains uninitialized. Change the line to:

```
btnA=new JButton("A");
```

(By the way, here's one case where it's safe--and perhaps even a clearer expression of your intent--to use `==` instead of calling `equals()`.)

Answer (score 4):

You are not using instance variable btnA in the constructor, but local variable btnA. That means your instance variable btnA will be still null.

The btnA from actionPerformed will be null.

Answer (score 2):

The following statement:

```
JButton btnA=new JButton("A");
```

Shadows your class member `btnA`. Replace it with:

```
btnA=new JButton("A"); // Without the type declaration
```

Answer (score 2):

`JButton btnA=new JButton("A");` the scope of this is in the constructor only. So it's not known in the actionPerformed function

change that to

```
btnA=new JButton("A");
```